# Merging two JSON data in nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I want to add the two JSON data in to one object..

this is Array name as MAPPER.

```
[ MAPPER {
     FieldOne: 'ABC',
     FieldTwo: 'City',
     FieldThree: 'John Wick
     FieldFour: '1234556789' } ]
```

And our json file is

```
[
{
userId: "1",
Title: "js",
Status: "done"
},
{
userId: "2",
Title: "nodejs",
Status: "pending"
},
{
userId: "3",
Title: "node1",
Status: "done"
}
]
```

what i want is to add this two into one JSON data..

so our final file will look like

```
[
    {
        userId: "1",
        Title: "js",
        Status: "done",
        FieldOne: 'ABC',
        FieldTwo: 'City',
        FieldThree: 'John Wick'
        FieldFour: '1234556789' 
    }
    and so on...
]
```

if any one this  please share up the things.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: have you tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and use `mapper` as template for a new object.

```js
var mapper = { FieldOne: 'ABC', FieldTwo: 'City', FieldThree: 'John.Wick', FieldFour: '1234567890' },
    data = [{ userId: "1", Title: "js", Status: "done" }, { userId: "2", Title: "nodejs", Status: "pending" }, { userId: "3", Title: "node1", Status: "done" }],
    result = data.map(o => Object.assign({}, mapper, o));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example)ping over one array and referencing the `mapper` array elements by their indices.

Combined with the [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) syntax you can merge the elements easily.

```
const combined = users.map((user, index) => {
    return {
        ...user,
        ...mapper[index]
    }
});
```